# Close React Native app automatically right after opening

Tags: react-native

I wanted to rename my react native project by using **react-native-rename** but after renaming and running the react-native run-android command I faced a problem that when I run the app on the device it closes automatically (maybe crashed).

Comment: Do you have Adnroid Studio? Open it and run the app. You should see logcat message in the debug area from the emulator/device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete watchman cache if you are using watchman

`watchman watch-del-all`

Clean npm cache

`npm start -- --reset-cache`